# Database and ViewPager in Android

Tags: android, database, user-interface, android-viewpager

I want to add fargments to viewpager in android app.But i want to create the fragments based on the details from a database .how should i overload getItem .that is the pages appear in order of database

Answer (score 0):

Create a `PagerAdapter` backed by a `Cursor`. Load the Cursor in the background using a `CursorLoader`. In `onLoadFinished()`, give the new `Cursor` to the adapter.

Use the data in the cursor when building your `ViewPager` pages. How you build them is up to you (use `PagerAdapter` if you are only providing `View`s; use `FragmentPagerAdapter` if you are providing `Fragment`s for the pages).

Loaders: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

ViewPager: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html